# Is there an MSBuild property providing the repository root?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops

When running from Visual Studio, MSBuild is given the [`$(SolutionDir)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019) macro/property.
Running from Azure DevOps, this property does not exist (rightfully so).

Azure DevOps has the [`Build.SourceBranch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) variable which can be passed to MsBuild as a property. This variable is better because it points directly to the repository root while `$(SolutionDir)` may point to a sub-directory if the solution is not in the root.

Is there a consistent MsBuild property I can use in both Visual Studio and Azure DevOps which can point to the repository root?

One way to achieve this is to have a `Directory.Build.props` file in the repository root and Specify a property `<RepositoryRoot>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</RepositoryRoot>` however one restriction I have prevents me from doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No, there isn't a default understanding of source control systems in MSBuild.

The `Directory.Build.props` file is likely the most robust approach, showing up regardless of building a solution or individual projects, since it stays the same regardless of the VCS system you use or migrate to/from.

Other approaches would need to hard code the VCS structure, e.g. looking for the a directory that contains a `.gitignore` file (which will not work if you don't use such a file):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RepoRoot>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('.gitignore', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))))</RepoRoot>
</PropertyGroup>
```